# Running supervisord process as root

Tags: python, supervisord, batch-processing

My goal is to run sudo inside one of the programs:

```
[program:doStaff]
command=sudo python manage.py doStaff
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/doStaff.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/doStaff.out.log
```

Here is [unix_http_server] from supervisord.conf:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock  
chmod=0770
```

Tried to set the supervisord user to root inside supervisord.conf but it didn't help.

I am trying to run this process as root since this script deletes some files in the system.

Answer (score 1):

In your program config (program:doStaff) add this line:

```
user=root
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup passwordless sudo for a user  and run your script as that user.

Edit sudoers file first :

> sudo visudo

At the end of that file add:

> scriptrunner  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Now run your script as scriptrunner user. You have to create that user of course.